# Can I make a default class in css?

Tags: css, class, default, styling

I'm working with a project that have several clases to use, but those classes doesn't cover all the existing cases, so I want to know a way to create a default class, so, if the element has not that property setted, the default value come in

Comment: Your question is not clear refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

**I hope Help you:**

```
$('your selectors').not('[class]').addClass('default');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div').not('[class]').addClass('default');
})
```

```css
.default {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<div class="x">Have class</div>
<div>Dont Have class</div>
<div class="y">Have class</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want, but I'm working with angular, and I did not say it, because I want to know if there is a pure css answer that allow me to handle it.

Comment: @JorgeWhitte  Unfortunately, no.there is not pure css.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following keywords to reset a property to its default. 
[`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) or [`unset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/unset). They are acceptable on all css properties.
`initial` sets the CSS property to its [initial value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial_value). `unset` also works like `initial` but acts a bit differently for elements that inherit styles from a parent. You can work with these properties and understand them here : [The inherit, initial, and unset values](https://www.quirksmode.org/css/cascading/values.html).

There is another property which you can use for changing all properties to default. [`all`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_all.asp).

**But do note that all these have limited support on IE.**

Ideal programming practice is to never add styles to your basic html tags (like `div`, `span` etc.) so that the defaults are preserved. And on elements you want styles add them through a `.class` or `#id` never on the `<tag>`.